# Como fazer upload de arquivos com Multer em dois storages diferentes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-aws, multer

Boa noite, preciso fazer o upload de um arquivo para uma pasta local (onde será tratado para comprimir o arquivo) e para o storage S3. a configuração do S3 e do armazenamento local com multer está programada e ambas funcionam de forma separada, quando eu coloco as duas configurações na mesma rota retorna undefined no segundo middleware do multer.

Formulário enviado:

```
var formulario = new FormData();

formulario.append('file', arquivo);

api.post('/postarArte', formulario).then((resposta) => {
    console.log(resposta);
});
```

rota com o middleware:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerConfig = require('./config/multerS3');
const multerLocal = require('./config/multerLocal');

// Rota para postar arte individual
router.post('/postarArte',   

    // Upload para a pasta local
    multerLocal.single('file'),

    // Upload para o storage S3
    multer(multerConfig).single('file'),

    // inserção no banco de dados
    postarArte
    
);
```

eu preciso do retorno da URL da imagem upada no S3 e do caminho da imagem armazenada localmente para gravar ambos no banco de dados, por isso pensei em usar a mesma rota. existe alguma configuração especifica para usar dois storages no multer (talvez no mesmo arquivo de configuração) ou alguma outra forma que resolva esse problema?

Configuração do multerLocal:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// Vamos exportar nosso módulo multer, executando com as nossas configurações em um objeto.
module.exports = (multer({

    // Como vai ser feito o armazenamento de aruqivos:
    storage: multer.diskStorage({

        // Destino do arquivo:
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {

            // setando o destino como segundo paramêtro do callback
            cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'images'));
        },

        // Como os arquivos vão ser chamados:
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {

            // Setando o nome do arquivo que vai ser salvado no segundo paramêtro
            // Apenas concatenei a data atual como o nome original do arquivo, que a biblioteca nos disponibiliza.
            cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname);

        },

        // Formatos aceitos:
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {

            const isAccepted = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'].find(formatoAceito => {
                formatoAceito == file.mimetype
            });

            // Formato aceito:
            if (isAccepted) {

                return cb(null, true);
            }

            // Formato inválido:
            return cb(null, false);
        }

    }),

  
}));
```

Configuração do multerS3

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const storageTypes = {

    s3: multerS3({

        s3: new aws.S3(),
        bucket: '*****',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        /** permissão, para que todo mundo consiga ler os arquivos */
        acl: 'public-read',
        /** nome da imagem que vai ser gravada no S3 */
        key: (req, file, callBack) => {

            crypto.randomBytes(16/** Tamanho do numero de bytes */, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) callBack(err);

                const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;
                callBack(null, fileName);
            });
        },
    }),
}

module.exports = {

    storage: storageTypes[process.env.STORAGE_TYPE],

    fileFilter: (req, file, callBack) => {
        const allowedMimes = [
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/png',
            'image/gif'
        ];

        if (allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            callBack(null, true);
        } else {
            callBack(new Error('Arquivo inválido'));
        };
    },
    
};
```

Configuração da função postarArte:

```
const conexao = require('../models/conexao');

function postarArte(req, resultado) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
    
    const { titulo, desc: descricao, tipo } = req.body;

    const { 
        originalname: nomeOriginal, 
        location: url, 
        key: chave, 
        size: tamanhoArquivo 
    } = req.file;

    valores = [
        [titulo, nomeOriginal, chave, descricao, tipo, url, tamanhoArquivo]
    ]

    conexao.query(`INSERT INTO postagem(titulo, nomeOriginal, chave, descricao, tipo, url, tamanhoArquivo) VALUES (?)`, valores, (req, res) => {
        return resultado.json()
    });    

};

module.exports = postarArte
```

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Já experimentaste um midleware teu onde corres os dois multer passando-lhe o `request`?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código completo? Assim fica difícil pra entender. Gostaria de ver o código completo da declaração das funções `multerLocal`, `multerConfig`, `multer` e a função `postarArte`.

Comment: @Sergio É uma boa ideia mas não sei como eu recupero os dados do formulário através de uma função ex: (req, res, next) => .... eu não sei onde fica os dados do formulário no req.body ou "req.form"(algo assim eu imagino) tem alguma ideia sobre isso?

Comment: @Danizavtz Editei a pergunta com a configuração dos outros arquivos.

Comment: O que estás a usar no Node? código nativo, express ou outra biblioteca?

Comment: @Sergio estou usando o express.

Comment: A que arrow function te referes?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de deixares o multer correr "sozinho" podes criar o teu middleware e interceptar as respostas do multer. Presumo que o problema é que o multer sobreescreve o `req.files`, nunca testei o multer encadeado dessa maneira mas presumo que o problema seja ele sobreescrever o `req.files`.

Podes fazer isso assim, é meio callback hell, e meio "sujo" pois insere chaves no objeto `req` (mas não vejo que seja um problema no namespace), mas que faz o que procuras:

```js
const multerLocal = multerLocal.single('file');
const multerS3 = multer(multerConfig).single('file');

router.post('/postarArte', (req, res, next) => {
  // chama o primeiro multer
  multerLocal(req, res, () => {
        // guarda o endereço do ficheiro
        req.multerLocalFiles = req.files;
 
        // chama o segundo multer (sequencialmente)
        multerS3(req, res, () => {

          // guarda o endereço do ficheiro
          req.multerS3Files = req.files;
          // deixa o express ir para o próximo middleware
          next();
        })
      }
    },

    // inserção no banco de dados
    postarArte
);
```

Comment: Eu fiz um teste e percebi que o multerS3 não é executado ele entra na arrow function mas não executa o arquivo de configuração multerConfig. Não consegui entender o porque. Mas obrigado pela resposta me deu algumas ideias estou testando.

Comment: @MatheusBraga: a que arrow function te referes?

Comment: @Serio essa: multerS3(req, res, () =>  ...

Comment: @MatheusBraga desculpa a resposta lenta, muito trabalho... O que te dá `console.log(req.files);` dentro de cada uma dessas arrow functions?

Comment: Te peço desculpas pelo mesmo! kkk ta tranquilo. Segue o log do req.files da primeira e da segunda arrow functions: [link] (https://github.com/bragaus/planoartistico-backend/blob/master/consoleLogArrowFunctions.txt)